# T-SQL sub query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was trying to build one query in SQL but was not being able to and need someone's help, the requirement is as below,

Extract only the accounts where there is no after_image = '0199d' present or if its presents the audit_Date should be < 20170701. Also unique accounts should be extracted. Please suggest

[image]

Comment: So what have you tried, why didn't it work? Also, please don't post images of text; text is text and should be posted as text. Tables can be posted as DLL and DML statements, well formatted tabular `text` or even as markdown tables.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Looks like homework?  Try to divide and conquer.  Come up with some queries that meet each of your criteria.  Start with what you want in the final results, then try to use where clauses to limit the rows based on the criteria.  It sounds like you need 'distinct ACCT'.  Then you want to remove ACCT values where XXX.  So write a query that finds distinct ACCT where XXX and do a not exists.  It sounds like you need to get the max AUDIT_DATE for that account also, do you need the AFTER_IMAGE for that row as well?

Comment: Please provide sample data in text format with desired output. And your effort should also be reflected.

Answer (score 0):

```
select acct, max(audit_date)from yourtable a
where not exists (select 1 from yourtable b where a.acct=b.acct and b.after_image = '0199d' 
and b.audit_Date >= '20170701')
group by acct
```

Comment: Answer's are great. But for best practices, please provide an explanation. You only posting code makes the OP and future commers copy and paste your answer without understanding the logic behind the answer. Please provide an answer with some explanation. Thank You!